# How to cancel dialog created on LocationSettingsRequest

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I am using LocationSettingsRequest to ask user to enable location following is my code

```
 LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
            final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates locationSettingsStates = locationSettingsResult.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:// All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location requests here.
                    //mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:// Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed by showing the user a dialog.
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);// Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();// Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:// Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

**It creates a dialog I want to cancel dialog is fragment is stopped how to do it there is no method for it**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you shouldn't call

```
status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
```

This will prevent the GPServices from showing up the dialog but you have to handle the state yourself.